# WordPress adding Question Mark to URL when using Hashtags in Nav

Tags: menus

I've got a site that I just want to have a dropdown on one of the nav items that uses `#` that scroll you down to another section of the page. Something like:

```
example.com/example <- Main page
 example.com/example/#section1 <- Part of main page
 example.com/example/#section2 <- Part of main page
```

This does work.

I would expect the address bar to read `example.com/example/#section1`. Instead what I get is: `example.com/example/?#section1`

I do not want the `?` in the URL.

This may be unrelated, but in order for the page not to reload when I click a sub item I have to use a `#` on the main nav item. Like `example.com/example/#header`. I would like to have the main nav item just be `example.com/example/`

Currently my menus are set like this in Wordpress:

`/example/` for main item
`/example/#section1` for sub item

I have tried `https://www.example.com/example/#section1` and `/example#section1` and `https://www.example.com/example#section1`

My ideal nav is this:

```
example.com/example/  |  example.com/example2  |   example.com/example3
 example.com/example/#section1
 example.com/example/#section2
```

Any help you can provide is appreciated!

Comment: Would you try switching to a bundled theme and see if the issue persists? If it does, try disabling all plugins too. I was not able to reproduce the issue. The `?` is not added to the URLs and the page does not reload. I'm using  `http://example.com/example/` and `http://example.com/example/#section1`.

Comment: The site is built on a totally custom theme. And it heavily relies on ACF. So for the most part if I change themes or disable plugins, the site is totally broken. But it does look like a plugin may be affecting it. With all plugins turned off, there's no more `?`. Guess I'll go by process of elimination to see what's causing it! Thanks for the input!

Comment: So it turns out it is an issue from a plugin. I am using Handl UTM Grabber to get UTM information and submit it through a form. I have contacted the creator for help and will post back if I get a response. Should I make this the answer to my question, or wait to see if I get a response?

Comment: Thank you for following up, Nick. Glad to hear you're homing in on the issue. Since third party themes and plugins are off-topic here on WPSE, it would be best to post your findings as an answer, then stop by in a couple of days to accept it to close it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out it is an issue from a plugin. I am using Handl UTM Grabber to get UTM information and submit it through a form. I have contacted the developer of the plugin and he is working on the issue.